# AngularJS: Multiple modules vs multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Still trying to wrap my head around the beast that is AngularJS and would like the opinions of Stack Overflow.  If I am designing an application with angular that is going to have SPA functionality, I would like to have some area where I can have "global" functions such something like a $scope.showMenu variable which can be bound with ng-class to a side bar menu so that when it is clicked it will slide out.

Having a collection of variables and functions that are available to all of the subsequent views in the application, where would these go?

My idea from reading about modules would be that I should make a parent module which has its own controller that contains all of my global level functions and variables and custom directives.

Then on "inner" content (when navigating around) each page should have its own module, complete with controllers, services and directives?

Thus my application might look something like the following

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="global" ng-controller="globalController">
   {{globalTest}}
     <div ng-controller="pageOneController">
        {{pageOneTest}}
     </div>

</body>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    angular.module('global',['pageOne']);
    angular.module('global').controller('globalController', globalController);
    globalController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function globalController($scope) {
         $scope.globalTest = "global test";
    }


    angular.module('pageOne',[]);
angular.module('pageOne').controller('pageOneController', pageOneController);
     pageOneController.$inject = ['$scope'];
     function pageOneController($scope) {
            $scope.pageOneTest = "page one test";
     }
```

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/wxja7smqOJiSbUi7mfu4?p=preview

Is this the proper "angular way" of going about making a large scale web application? Or is it better to just have a single "module" and have multiple controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to put your global code into a factory/service and to inject that service wherever you need the code.

For example:

```
angular.module('something')
    .factory('something', function() {
      return {
        doSomething: function() {}
      ...
```

And in your controller, after you inject it, you can attach it to your scope by doing something like:

```
$scope.myControllerFn = something.doSomething
```

Comment: I don't fully understand how that would work.  If I had a side menu for instance which had a binding of ng-class={'show-menu': showMenu == true} and $scope.showMenu was in my controller, how could a factory call somehow change the controller's scope variable?  The hypothetical functions I am talking about would be simple things (not calling services or anything).  Ex: $scope.openMenu = function() {  $scope.showMenu = true; }.  If I put that function in a factory I don't see how it could work?

Comment: Well, for your sidebar example, the BEST way to do this would be to use something like UI router to properly reflect the different UI states of your app.

One other thing is that, you also have the general idea right about how you could just have a parent controller wrapping everything. My question with that then is, how would that be much different than just throwing everything on $rootScope? Using factories/services to do this keeps your global scope "clean" by allowing you to DI them in where you need them and would allow for easier-to-write unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

For a Single Page Application (SPA), I am inclined to keep all my controllers in a single module. When using multiple controllers, I would use the `controller as binding` syntax.

```
<body ng-app="global" ng-controller="globalController as global">
   {{global.Test}}
     <div ng-controller="pageController as child">
        {{child.Test}}
     </div>

</body>
```